# I can't step into qt source code on Windows

Tags: qt5

I am using Qt5.5.0 to build application in QtCreator. Everything worked fine except stepping into qt src code. When I added the Qt Src directory and corresponded pdb files, I still can't step into Qt source code.

Comment: Could you explain me better please

Comment: I've added the Qt src directory and related pdb files in QtCreator on Windows. However when I debugged my program, I couldn't step into qt source code.

Comment: I have solved the problem after I downloaded Qt5.8.0 and installed it. Maybe the problem is just in Qt5.5.0 because of the incorrect pdb files downloaded from Qt official website.

Comment: Please post your answer so others can easily solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem after I downloaded Qt5.8.0 and installed it. Maybe the problem is just in Qt5.5.0 because of the incorrect pdb files downloaded from Qt official website.

Answer (score 1):

In Qt creator go to `Tools` -> `Options` -> `Debbugger` -> `General` and add source directory in sectin "Source Path Mapping"

[image]

Comment: I have done this, but it didn't work. I'm sure I have the correct Src files because I installed qt5 with Src selected.

Answer (score 0):

For Qt 6, open the Qt Maintenance Tool, and install this package: Qt->Qt 6.x.x->Qt Debug Information Files.